# How do I specify which kind of version of soap do I use with webServiceTemplate?

Tags: web-services, spring, soap, spring-ws

I am developing a soap web service client with spring.

I am using `webServiceTemplate`

How do I specify which kind of version of soap do I use?

I can see that it s using soap 1.1 by default.

I want to force it to use soap 1.2

How can I do that?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
<bean id="messageFactory" class="org.springframework.ws.soap.saaj.SaajSoapMessageFactory">
    <property name="soapVersion">
        <util:constant static-field="org.springframework.ws.soap.SoapVersion.SOAP_12"/>
    </property>
</bean>
```

i just found, i need to pass a message Factory

Answer (score 2):

You just specify the *soap* version in the configuration file of *spring* usually `spring.cfg.xml` in the following way:

```
<bean id="messageFactory" class="org.springframework.ws.soap.saaj.SaajSoapMessageFactory">
    <property name="soapVersion">
        <util:constant static-field="org.springframework.ws.soap.SoapVersion.SOAP_12"/>
    </property>
</bean>
```